# How to print the following in NASM assembler?

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am still learning how to use NASM so there may be some syntax mistakes in my question. Anyway, when I create a label, suppose

```
buf: resb 16
```

Then, the label `buf` contains a memory address that points to the first of the 16 bytes that were reserved. Then, I want to print everything from an arbitrary byte in those 16 to the very last one, say, print the bytes 13 through 16. Then the code would look something like

```
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, buf + 12
mov edx, 4         ;; for the 4 bytes to be read 
int 80h
```

Is this correct? Then, what I am actually trying to do is

```
some_number:     resb 1

mov [some_number], byte 3

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, buf + 16 - [some_number]
mov edx, byte [some_number]         ;; for the 3 bytes to be read, in this case 
int 80h
```

so I want to pass the address buf + (16 - 3) which is buf + 13. But this definitely does not work. Let me know if this is wrong or if there is a better way to achieve this.

By the way, `some_number` will be determined by an arbitrary process so it will be different each time my program runs.

Comment: Show how you're printing? No way to know if those registers are correct otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the system interrupt. I want to write to standard output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mov ecx, buf + 12` is invalid, but you can achieve that by using `lea ecx, [buf + 12]` which is pretty much "*load effective address of buf + 12*" and that's what you want.

While the effective address format does allow registers, it doesn't allow indirection or subtraction, so `lea ecx, [buf + 16 - [some_number]]` would be doubly invalid. You will have to do the subtraction in a separate step, taking care to use the proper operand size. One option would be:

```
lea ecx, [buf + 16]
movzx eax, byte [some_number]
sub ecx, eax
```

If your `some_number` were a dword not a byte, you could simplify that to:

```
lea ecx, [buf + 16]
sub ecx, [some_number]
```